# Symfon2 Spit out 3 text fields with a widget

Tags: php, forms, symfony, entity

Can I set a widget such that it can spit out 1-3 text fields depending on the desired format?  I have a Coordainate entity with a long and lat field. Some of ours users prefer Degrees Minutes Seconds, some Degrees Minutes, some Decimal. We have customizations to handle this on our current system (Symfony 1.4) and I would like to use these same customization files. I'm sure that's passed in through the options?

Here's my form class:

```
    <?php
   namespace ***\adminBundle\Form;

   use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
   use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
   use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class CoordinateType extends AbstractType
{
        /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('gps84Lat')
            ->add('gps84Long')          
            ->getForm()
        ;
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
     */
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => '***\adminBundle\Entity\Coordinate'
        ));
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return '***_adminbundle_coordinate';
    }
}
```

**EDIT: example use of the customization file:

```
    $custom = $options['attr']['customization_file'];
    $cf     = $custom['form'];

            if(!array_key_exists(0, $cf['fields']['field']))
                    $cf['fields']['field']  = array($cf['fields']['field']);

            foreach($cf['fields']['field'] as $field)
            {
                if(in_array($field['name'], array('gps_84_lat', 'gps_84_long')))
                {
                    if($field['format'] == 'dms')
                    {
                        // standard degrees-minutes-seconds GPS field
                        if($field['name'] == 'gps_84_lat')
                            $gps    = $this->getObject()->getGps84Lat();
                        elseif($field['name'] == 'gps_84_long')
                            $gps    = $this->getObject()->getGps84Long();
                        else
                            $gps    = '';

                        // degrees
                        $this->setWidget($field['name'].'_degrees', CustomWidgetExtender::createSfWidget($field, $user, $this));
                        $this->widgetSchema->setLabel($field['name'].'_degrees', $field['label']);

                        if(!$this->isNew())
                            $this->setDefault($field['name'].'_degrees', DataMan::getGpsDeg($gps));
                        elseif(trim($field['default']) != '')
                            $this->setDefault($field['name'].'_degrees', DataMan::getGpsDeg($field['default']));

                        // minutes
                        $this->setWidget($field['name'].'_minutes', CustomWidgetExtender::createSfWidget($field, $user, $this));
                        $this->widgetSchema->setLabel($field['name'].'_minutes', $field['label']);

                        if(!$this->isNew())
                            $this->setDefault($field['name'].'_minutes', DataMan::getGpsMin($gps));
                        elseif(trim($field['default']) != '')
                            $this->setDefault($field['name'].'_minutes', DataMan::getGpsMin($field['default']));

                        // seconds
                        $this->setWidget($field['name'].'_seconds', CustomWidgetExtender::createSfWidget($field, $user, $this));
                        $this->widgetSchema->setLabel($field['name'].'_seconds', $field['label']);

                        if(!$this->isNew())
                            $this->setDefault($field['name'].'_seconds', DataMan::getGpsSec($gps));
                        elseif(trim($field['default']) != '')
                            $this->setDefault($field['name'].'_seconds', DataMan::getGpsSec($field['default']));

                        // add field name to use_fields array
                        array_push($use_fields, $field['name'].'_degrees');
                        array_push($use_fields, $field['name'].'_minutes');
                        array_push($use_fields, $field['name'].'_seconds');

                    }
                    elseif($field['format'] == 'dm')
                    {
                        // degrees-decimal minutes GPS field
                        if($field['name'] == 'gps_84_lat')
                            $gps    = $this->getObject()->getGps84Lat();
                        elseif($field['name'] == 'gps_84_long')
                            $gps    = $this->getObject()->getGps84Long();
                        else
                            $gps    = '';

                        // degrees
                        $this->setWidget($field['name'].'_degrees', CustomWidgetExtender::createSfWidget($field, $user, $this));
                        $this->widgetSchema->setLabel($field['name'].'_degrees', $field['label']);

                        if(!$this->isNew())
                            $this->setDefault($field['name'].'_degrees', DataMan::getGpsDeg($gps));
                        elseif(trim($field['default']) != '')
                            $this->setDefault($field['name'].'_degrees', DataMan::getGpsDeg($field['default']));

                        // minutes
                        $this->setWidget($field['name'].'_minutes', CustomWidgetExtender::createSfWidget($field, $user, $this));
                        $this->widgetSchema->setLabel($field['name'].'_minutes', $field['label']);

                        if(!$this->isNew())
                            $this->setDefault($field['name'].'_minutes', DataMan::getGpsMin($gps, 5));
                        elseif(trim($field['default']) != '')
                            $this->setDefault($field['name'].'_minutes', DataMan::getGpsMin($field['default'], 5));

                        // add field name to use_fields array
                        array_push($use_fields, $field['name'].'_degrees');
                        array_push($use_fields, $field['name'].'_minutes');

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // standard decimal degrees GPS field
                        $this->setWidget($field['name'], CustomWidgetExtender::createSfWidget($field, $user, $this));
                        $this->widgetSchema->setLabel($field['name'], $field['label']);

                        if(trim($field['default']) != '')
                            $this->setDefault($field['name'], $field['default']);

                        // add field name to use_fields array
                        array_push($use_fields, $field['name']);

                    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditions in your builder method basing on what is in options:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    if(<some state of options>) {
        $builder->add(...);
    }
    // and so on
}
```

By the way, what do you mean by 'customizations to handle this'?

Comment: They are customization files in XML format. I added an in example of how we use it in our current website. And using those conditions can I set it to spit out 3 fields instead of just one? 'gps84Lat' is a 'double' type in the table and the default is just going to spit out a single field in the template. if($field['format'] == 'dms') I want it to spit out 3 text fields.